# Engagement Time Calculation When App Is In Background

Tags: android, firebase, analytics, firebase-analytics, android-instrumentation

How to calculate engagement time whenever my app is in background. User engagement (firebase automatically collected event) calculate periodically, while the app is in the foreground.
But how to add the time in user engagement when my app is in back ground. Or i need to instrument other event..
Any Idea????

Answer (score 1):

When your app is in the background, the user isn't "engaged" with it at all.  With newer versions of Android, the OS may immediately kill your backgrounded app at any time without warning, so it's even more difficult to calculate a meaningful metric for background time.  It seems to me that background time is a mostly meaningless metric, in terms of analytics.  [Background time has a use in Firebase Performance Monitoring](https://firebase.google.com/docs/perf-mon/automatic), but app performance in this respect isn't the same as analytics.

Comment: But if a user is listening an audio podcast in background using my app then it's a engagement. Please correct me if i m wrong in this. @Doug Stevenson

Comment: Then define and use a special event to measure this special case.  There is no way for Firebase to know why the app is in the background, so you need to do something special to indicate what's happening.

Comment: @DougStevenson I am looking to solve this problem too. We have not created a special event for our music player which continues to run in the background even if the app quits. Does that mean there is no way for us to get the time users spent with music with app in background? Isn't this a system flaw because extend_session was introduced only last year if I am not wrong. Event if it was there, not everyone knew how to use it because of lack of proper documentation which means inaccurate session time calculations.