# Android Firebase session calculation for app which is in background

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-analytics

I'm trying to figure out how can I apply [this guide](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/9191807#) to my code and this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52307287/engagement-time-calculation-when-app-is-in-background), precisely:

> A session begins to time out when an app is moved to the background,
>   but you have the option to extend that session by logging the
>   extend_session parameter (with a value of 1) on events logged while
>   the app is in the background.

This is my code (which I want to use on events, when my service is running and activities are on pause / stop):

```
Bundle params = new Bundle();
params.putInt("extend_session", 1);
firebaseAnalytics.logEvent("app_in_background", params);
```

The *event* is custom, because default one doesn't suite my need.

Long story short, I want to see how much time (average) the service is running and possibly having this data listed in **Where are your users engaged?** table (Firebase console).

What I want to achieve is: *how much my users are engaged while using my app service ?*
Am I using the correct approach ?

Comment: Hi, looking at the timestamp on this post, I am guessing you would have figured a solution to this by now. Do you mind sharing here as to how you solved it for background services? I am building an app that continues to play music even when the app activity is in the background (close/minimized). Appreciate your help. - A.S

Comment: @AbhishekSharma sorry for the late answer. I give up to find a solution.